# launch Edge Canary with launch.json

Tags: microsoft-edge, vscode-debugger

Some time ago, the setting in launch.json would launch Edge Canary

```
 "type": "msedge", 
 "version": "canary",
 "request": "launch",
```

Now it opens the normal edge instead.
Any changes I am not aware of?

Thanks

Comment: version is not valid for launch.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the `runtimeExecutable` property:

```json
{
  "request": "launch",
  "type": "msedge",
  "runtimeExecutable": "canary",
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes